# Insert Video Clip in another Video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to insert a video clip in another video at specified position (after n seconds). I am thinking to slice the main video first and then concatenate the pieces again. But this solution is not looking promising to me as what if I have to insert the video clips at multiple locations in the main video? Is there any better way of doing this in ffmpeg?
thanks

Comment: See [How to concatenate clips from the same video with ffmpeg](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/10401/1760). Adding another input is trivial, but may require additional filtering if the inputs vary too much in frame size, frame rate, timebase, etc.

Comment: thanks LordNeckbeard for the link and introducing forum just dedicated to video manipulations.